# Are changes in a submodule committed to my local repo or to the repo the sobmodule was created from?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I read a couple of articles about submodules but I haven't figured this out yet.

Given this structure

```
+ my-repo
+ --- + somepkg
+ --- + submod
```

I made changes to `submod` which I would like to keep all nicely within `myrepo`. If I commit the changes in `submod`, then push - will the upstream repo from which I created the submodule be changed in any way or am I just keeping everything in my repo?

My targeted solution is that I can maintain my own copy of that submodule, ideally internally in `my-repo`. Maybe submodules aren't the best option here? I don't have rights upstream...so maybe I should first create a fork of that, then push there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I made changes to `submod` which I would like to keep all nicely within `myrepo`.

The think to understand here is: submodules are separate repositories. Their content is incorporated into the working tree but into the parent repository (called superproject).

> If I commit the changes in submod, then push - will the upstream repo from which I created the submodule be changed in any way

No. If you don't have rights to push they simply refuse your push, `git push` returns an error.

> My targeted solution is that I can maintain my own copy of that submodule, ideally internally in `my-repo`.

You are on the right track but not there yet. You cannot save changes from a submodule in the superproject.

You need to fork the `submod` original repository to your own repo to which you have all the rights and change remote names. The traditional names are: `upstream` for the initial repo and `origin` for your fork. When you want to incorporate changes from the upstream you do `git pull upstream`. When you want to push you push to your fork: `git push origin`.

In the superproject `my-repo` you also need to change `.gitmodules`: change `submod` URL to your fork. Also you need to add, commit and push any changes in `submod` because superprojects store the current commit reference (called "gitlink") for every submodule.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution besides [submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76638125/7976758) would be [`git subtree`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-subtree). To incorporate `submod` into `my-repo`:

```
git subtree -P submod add upstream_URL master # or other branch
```

Now `submod` will be fully incorporated into `my-repo` so you just add/commit/push one repository. When you need to integrate changes from the upstream to `submod`:

```
git subtree -P submod pull upstream_URL master
```

See the [docs](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt).

Comment: Oh this is interesting, I did not know this exists. I already created the subnmodule, so I need to think if I can switch to this.